# Downloading image from url using python-requests recieving error 403:Forbidden

Tags: image, download, python-requests, python-3.8

So Im trying to download image but server response is "403". I have tried using other user-agents if it has any sense but it doesn't work. With other links code works well. I don't know how i can circumvent server or smth.

```
import requests
import shutil

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36'
}


r = requests.get('https://s8.mkklcdnv6temp.com/mangakakalot/b1/bd926355/chapter_3/1.jpg', 
    headers=headers,
    stream=True)
if r.status_code == 200:
    with open("img.png", 'wb') as f:
        r.raw.decode_content = True
        shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)
else:
    print('failure')
```

Comment: Have you tried this in a browser?  I get the same result.  They're using CloudFlare security.  My guess is they won't allow you to fetch the image unless you just fetched their web page that includes the image.

Comment: @TimRoberts yep i tried browser, i tried selenium with disabled automation flag and other things that still works on 78 chrome version but сloudflare still doesn't give me access, also tried other methods to download but no, sadge.